# .Net Remoting or Any .net tool

Tags: .net, remoting

I have one individual dll on server. If there is any change happened in dll I want dll inform me about that change. by any events or any other thing  which is possible. I never work with .net remoting. Please let me know what I can do?

Comment: Whip up a quick Google search for .NET Remoting, and also show us what you have done so far. StackOverflow is not a code-on-demand website, it's a help website where you show us what you've done and we'll assist.

Comment: You can implement a service or recurring scheduled app which will compare file hash and metadata with expected, and notify otherwise. In order to improve my answer, could you specify why would you need to monitor changes of remote DLL?

Comment: The question is too generic to answer apropriately. There are tons of possible situations fitting your question. You should be more precise so that we can help you figure out.